# C# adding random values "string" to a column in database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have been adding random values to my database using the following Statement in visual studio and it works just fine for two values.

```
  Random rd;
  TextBox_Language.Text = rd.Next(2) == 0 ? "EN" : "FR";
```

Now I need to have more than just two strings and I have tried the bellow Code, but that doesn't work. Any one got a hint on how to get around with it?

```
 TextBox_Language.Text = rd.Next(3) == 0 ? "EN" : "FR" : "DE"; // doesn't work
```

Comment: The `?:` operator checks a condition and only returns the value you specify for true and false. You cannot include a third value without an additional condition to check when using that operator. See the documentation on [**?: Operator**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) for more details on the Conditional Operator Expression

Comment: The conditional operator `?:` can return one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are trying to expand the conditional operator will make it unnecessarily complex. You can put the values in `string array` and use the randon number as *index* of that array to get the strings.

```
string []valuesArray = new string[] {"EN",  "FR", "DE"};    
TextBox_Language.Text = valuesArray[rd.Next(valuesArray.Length)];
```

**Note:** This method will allow you to given any number of element with random number. Using the [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) will make it even more flexible. You can add / remove any element at any time unlike array.

```
List<string> valuesList = new List<string> {"EN" , "FR" , "DE"};    
valuesList.Add("FE"); //Added one more element
string s = valuesList[rd.Next(valuesList.Count)];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Adil, it actually works for more than 3 I added Turkish as well.

Comment: You are welcome, yes it would work for any size. Using List would make it more flexible. See my updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary variable and then cascade the `? :` operator.

```
int temp = rd.Next(3);
TextBox_Language.Text = temp == 0 ? "EN" : temp == 1 ? "FR" : "DE";
```